# Should I check Debugger.IsAttached before Debugger.Break or Debug.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm wondering if I should call `if(Debugger.IsAttached)` before calling other Debug and Debugger functions?

```
if(Debugger.IsAttached) { Debugger.Break(); }
```

vs.

```
Debugger.Break() // Without checking if Debugger is actually attached
```

Comment: The 2nd way works, easy enough to try yourself.  The jit debugger window is not particularly pretty and this must be avoided in production code since it crashes the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on why you're calling the `Break()` method. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx):

> If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a
>   debugger.

If you don't want to bother users who aren't currently debugging, then you should test for attachment first. If you don't care (or in fact would like the prompt) then don't check.

Comment: +1 to you. I completely misunderstood the question, and you got it right.

Comment: So it will prompt user to attach debugger even if program is ran in Release mode?

Comment: @Jaakko I believe that is correct. Debuggers can be attached to release-mode compiled programs (though their utility is reduced, since release mode won't generate .pdb files or helpful `nop`s.)